# Why does Edge performance timeline shows that assets are being requested before HTML parsing?

Tags: performance, microsoft-edge, timeline, web-inspector

From what I know, the browser can only request the assets (JS, CSS) after parsing the HTML. But analyzing the "Performance" tab on Edge's DevTools, the "Send Request" for the `w3schools30.css` stylesheet happens before the parsing is even started, as we can see indicated by the green arrow and other data in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY2EG.png).

I'm using a simple example. Here's `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3schools30.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        Performance testing
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the `index.js`:

```
setTimeout(() => {}, 1000)
```

Am I misunderstanding the timeline or there is a circunstance where this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is related with a feature called "preload scanner" on Chromium browsers. [This article](https://web.dev/preload-scanner/) says:

> A preload scanner's role is speculative, meaning that it examines raw
> markup in order to find resources to opportunistically fetch before
> the primary HTML parser would otherwise discover them.